# How do I only show edittext for current user's listview item?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I've searched for this question already, and I couldn't find it anywhere, and I'm not even sure how to exactly word it.

I have a listview with images, text, buttons, etc. for each item. I also have an edittext for the items, but I only want the edittext to be visible for the current user. The same way you're only able to edit your own post on Facebook, not every other one as well.

Here's what I've tried:

```
holder.editcaption = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);

(...)

if(mCurrentUser.getUsername()!=currentItem.getSender())
    holder.editcaption.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

This is in the getView() of the adapter. The problem is that either all of the edittexts become invisible or visible when I only need every edittext except for the current user's to be invisible. I only need the edittext view of the current item to change.

Any help is very much appreciated.

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<GalleryItem>{

    public MyListAdapter(){
        super(getActivity(), R.layout.item_view, thelist);

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(items.get(position).getUsername()!=mCurrentUser.getUsername())
            return 2;
        else return 0;
    }

@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

          currentItem = adapter.getItem(position);

          int type = getItemViewType(position);

         ViewHolder holder; 
        View itemView = null;
        if(convertView == null){
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getListView().getContext().getSystemService(     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
if(type==0)
itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
else
itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currentuser_item_view, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();          
        holder.image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
        holder.text =  (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.newtext);
        holder.profilepicture = (ProfilePictureView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
        holder.timelabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeposted);
        holder.post_caption = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.caption);
        holder.editcaption = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        itemView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{


            itemView = convertView;
            holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
            }
```

Comment: perhaps check out http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html

Comment: I had thought about whether there was a way to do different item views earlier, but I figured it would be too much of a hassle, but it looks like it is actually a thing. I'm going to try it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, because of the way that ListViews recycle the views for each item, you cannot simply edit the view when getView() is called. That same view may be reused for another element in the list.

Comment: Thanks, but I am having a bit of trouble. In the example, he decides what to inflate based on the return of int type. In my situation, I need to decide based on currentItem.getUsername(). 

I tried this: `if(currentItem.getSender()!=mCurrentUser.getUsername())
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false);
else
 convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.currentuser_item_view, parent, false);`

It didn't work.

Comment: If anyone has any suggestions, feel free to help me out. This is going to drive me nuts.

Comment: post your `getview` completely!!